# Windows Explorer error, while open any folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I have the next problem while I try to open any folder in my notebook. This problem is not repeated every time but this problem is fluent.
When problem is rise i saw pop up window (you can see it on pic.)
[image]

I really don't know why it can happen, I read some articles about this problem, but not find a way how to fix it yet.

Comment: please translate the dialog text into english...

Comment: Normally this happens because of a problem in a shell plugin or even a virus. Normally anti-virus/spyware software can get rid of it for you.

Comment: "Work of explorer is stop" and "Windows trying to find a way to fix this problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i decide this problem by reinstall programms like skype,FF browser several others programms.